# Spotify API: Get user owned playlists only

Tags: spotify

During developing a little spotify widget I want to receive my playlists. This is no problem with the Spotify API but I need to get only the playlists where the owner is the current user.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Julian

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-users-saved-tracks/

Comment: This endpoint (`get-users-saved-tracks`) returns the user's saved tracks. This is different from the playlists that the user has created.

Answer (score 4):

Julian, there's no API endpoint to *only* retrieve the endpoints that the user has created. Instead, your application needs to retrieve the [Current User's list of Playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/) and loop through them to filter out the user's own playlists by the `owner` property. (See [Playlist object](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/#playlist-object-full) for details.)

If you don't know the user's username, use the [Get Current User's Profile](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/) endpoint.

Comment: This would be great as an option you could pass to the get user playlists method... at present it's incredibly inefficient. If we could request 50 user owned playlists, it's likely this would get all playlists for the vast majority of users. With the current way, we have to request multiple times and filter, meaning multiple API calls and a lot of useless data transfer!